# PHP: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, database, mysqli

So i have the 3 tables as below:

Table `company`:

[image]

Table `address`:

[image]

Table `company_address`:

[image]

---

I tried to add address information to specific company by getting `company_id` from `$_GET` and `address_id` using `mysqli_insert_id`. But when I commit, it just give me the error

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`chkdcrm`.`company_address`, CONSTRAINT `company_address_company_id` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`company_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Where is the problem? I can't figure it out...

---

The php code:

```
<?php
  require_once '../conn.php';
  $company_id = isset($_GET['company_id'])? $_GET['company_id'] : '';
  //Defining variables and parameters...
  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO address ... VALUES ...";
  //Binding parameters...
  $address_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt1);

  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO company_address (company_id, address_id) VALUES 
  ($company_id, $address_id)";
  mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

  mysqli_close($conn);}
?>
```

---

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chkdcrm`.`company_address` (
  `address_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`, `company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `company_address_address_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`)
    REFERENCES `chkdcrm`.`address` (`address_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `company_address_company_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`)
    REFERENCES `chkdcrm`.`company` (`company_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chkdcrm`.`address` (
  `address_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` ENUM('Invoice', 'Shipping', 'Site', 'Mailing') NOT NULL,
  `street` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `zip` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `country` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chkdcrm`.`company` (
  `company_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_de` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL  ,
  `website` VARCHAR(255) NULL  ,
  `parent_company` INT(11) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `parent_company`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_company`)
    REFERENCES `chkdcrm`.`company` (`company_id`)
    ON DELETE SET NULL)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score -1):

i have gone through this a lot.. the only thing i can tell you is you have to delete all the references in other tables, to be able to delete something that has a constraint.

i have a feeling that you're trying to insert into table2 a ID value that doesn't exist in table1. (if it gets hectic i suggest disabling foreign key checks before performing any operation on the table.

you would simply

```
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

This will disable foreign key matching against any other tables. After you are done with the table enable it again

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to check whether the submitted company id does exist in its parent table (company). If it does, then it should work.

```
$checkcomp = "SELECT 1 FROM company WHERE company_id = $company_id";
$checking = $conn->query($checkcomp);
if($checking->num_rows > 0){
  //execute your insert
}
else{some error handling
}
```

Side note, I'd rather use POST instead of GET

Comment: In this case, the company_id does exist in the parent table with company_id=4. I used $_GET to get the company_id from the URL, therefore $company_id should have the value of 4...

Comment: `$checkcomp = "SELECT 1 FROM company WHERE company_id = $company_id";` is a security breach as `$company_id` can potentially be used to inject SQL

Comment: It is indeed. Keep in mind that my approach back then was purely assuming a theoretical environment where OP doesn't have to worry about any security issues. The above is basically the gist of the matter, with security left as an exercise to OP.